# print() not working

Tags: ios, swift

I can't find what is the problem. When I press button on simulator it doesn't print anything.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func PressButton(_ sender: UIButton){
         print("Something")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the circle to the left of your @IBAction filled in or hollow?

Comment: Check outlet connection in storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you never connected your outlet. There are a couple ways to do this, but let's do it in your storyboard file.

---

**1.** Navigate to your storyboard hosting the `View Controller Scene` (most likely *Main.storyboard*).

**2.** Open up the Document Outline.

**3.** Control-drag from your *UIButton* to *View Controller* and under `Sent Events`, select your method `PressButton:`.

[image: Connecting a UIButton to an outlet in ViewController]

---

You should be good to go after that. Good luck!